# zu + Infinitive within relative clause

Tags: infinitive, relative-clause

I want to use a *zu* + Infinitive construction within a relative clause, but I wasn’t sure what the word order should be.

> The film I have chosen to study is *the Lives of Others.*

Would the *zu studieren* go within or after the relative clause?

> Der Film, den ich zu studieren gewählt habe, ist *das Leben der Anderen.*

or

> Der Film, den ich gewählt habe, zu studieren, ist *das Leben der Anderen.*

Comment: I think "studieren" is the wrong word here. I would rephrase it to: _Den Film, den ich untersuchen werde (future)/den ich untersucht habe (past)/für den ich mich entschieden habe, ist „Das Leben der Anderen"._

Comment: @Iris Why do you say `den Film` (Akkusativ), rather than Nominativ, when it is at the start of the main clause, using *sein*?

Comment: @Iris Does that not just make the relative pronoun, *Der Film, **den** ich…*, accusative, without affecting the article in the main clause?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure what's correct: "der Film" or "den Film". My native feeling of language fails here... (but I think, you are right, that my "den Film" is wrong)

Comment: The correct sentence has to start with: "Der Film, den ich..." (native speaker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Korrekterweise würde man wohl sagen:

> Der Film, **den** ich zum Studieren gewählt habe, hat den Titel *das Leben der Anderen.*

Dies liegt an dem Wort *gewählt.* Der zu + Infinitiv wäre hier meiner Meinung nach falsch. Allerdings würde es heißen:

> Der Film, **den** ich versucht habe zu studieren, hat den Titel *das Leben der Anderen.*

Das kann folgendermaßen begründet werden:

- Ich versuche etwas zu tun. (zu + Infinitiv) / Ich habe versucht etwas zu tun.
- Ich wähle etwas. / Ich habe etwas gewählt.

Das Relativpronomen muss *den* heißen, da der Film im Akkusativ steht. 
Frage: *Wen oder was* habe ich zum Studieren gewählt? Antwort: den Film

Answer (score 3):

In a written text the most elegant word order if we want to stay close to your construction is

> Der Film, den zu studieren ich gewählt habe, ist *das Leben der anderen.*

This does however sound somewhat formal, so one would probably choose a different construction.

Now regarding the choice of words: As has been noted in the comments, *studieren* may not be the best choice, for example *untersuchen* could be better. And *I choose to do sth* can be translated with *ich entschließe/entscheide mich, etw. zu tun*. Here however, *wählen* is actually a good choice if it refers to the movie, not its study, as in Max’ answer.